# How to Target .net Framework 7.0 in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I just installed the Visual Studio Community 2022 and installed .net core 4.8.1 (ndp481-web.exe and the dotnet-sdk-7.0.102-win-x64.exe.) Dotnet 7.0 is not a preview, it is the released version, and VSCommunity 2022 is the released version.

```
C:\\Users\\TimE\>dotnet --list-sdks  
5\.0.101 \[C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk\]  
5\.0.416 \[C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk\]  
7\.0.102 \[C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk\]
```

However, I cannot target the .Net 7.0 framework for my existing applications.
7.0 does not appear in the dropdown. [VS2022 Target Framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5D9Mo.jpg)

Does anyone know what I need to do to get my existing apps to target the 7.0 framework?
Am I missing a setting to show the Framework instead of the Core?

Thanks much in advance!

Comment: You can't get there until you pick the correct project template to get started.  Right now you created it from one that had ".NET Framework" in its name.  That targets the legacy framework.  Instead pick one that is labeled ".NET".

Comment: Those are .NET Framework versions. Create .NET (not .NET Framework) app and you will have .NET 5/6/7 available.

Comment: Ah. Is there a way I can target existing Solutions/projects to use the 7.0 framework, is there a setting I can change, or am I locked in to using 4.8.1 for those? When I choose 'Retarget Projects, my only options are 10.0 (latest installed version)

Comment: Ugh, to answer my own question: not easily.  I can run an analyzer from VS2019 or run an APIPort tool.  Good times.

Answer (score 0):

.Net Framework needs to be migrated to .net core for those who want to know. The proper way to do this is outlined at the Microsoft documentation page [Overview of porting from .NET Framework to .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting)